# Getting Java Applet to play as standalone Application

Tags: java, applet

I've spent the last few days putting together a game that runs as an Applet, but I would also like to have it available as an Application.

I've tried placing the applet in a frame, but I only get a black screen (and the occasional menu screen) when doing so. The applet still runs and the sound still plays, but there is nothing else.

I would like to not have to break down the code and rewrite it for a standalone application, as it's time consuming, but if there's no other way, then I'll do what I have to do. The program is a little complex in that the "main" class (containing all the media information, game related events, etc.) is an extension of an Applet class (containing the `KeyListener`, `init()` event, `run()` event, etc.) so maybe I am just trying to place the wrong thing in a frame?

Here is a link to the src folder for the game. I have tried putting both the AWPASG class and the Game class in a frame and seen the same results for both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Source Code/Media
http://www.mediafire.com/?4eslqqr4aoh33j1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your class design is not very good. You've bunched everything together in 2 classses, isntead of separating at least the UI Widgets (panels, etc, etc) from the UI Container.

Also you're using the old style AWT Applet and Panel. You should use the new Swing JApplet and JPanel (and all opthers JXxx components)

In short, try isolating your GUI building (painting) into a class that extends JPanel (or contains a JPanel). Then you can have 2 separate startup classes, one that puts your game JPanel inside a JApplet and one that puts it into a JFrame (and thus gives you the possibility to start it as a Desktop application).

Also you might want to separate your GAME init logic from the Applet init lifecycle, your game should be able to initialize without caring about the underlieing GUI technology.

Comment: Well, bummer! Thanks so much for this info. I'll have to start converting over to Swing components, I guess. I'm still fairly new to the programming scene, so I'll work on cleaning my class design up. Some of it is over my head, but that's why the internet exists.